# I have issue with website on python, clicking the button redicrects to /result instead of /test

Tags: python, flask, web

After clicking on button code reirect me on "/result" indtead of "/test", help me please to fix it

quiz.py (main code):

```
import os
from random import shuffle
from flask import Flask, session, request, redirect, render_template, url_for
from db_scripts import get_question_after, get_quises, check_answer

def start_quiz(quiz_id):
    session['quiz'] = quiz_id
    session['last_question'] = 0
    session['answers'] = 0
    session['total'] = 0

def end_quiz():
    session.clear()

def quiz_form():
    q_list = get_quises()
    return render_template('start.html', q_list=q_list)

def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        start_quiz(-1)
        return quiz_form()
    else:
        quest_id = request.form.get('quiz')
        start_quiz(quest_id)
        return redirect(url_for('test', _method='POST'))


def save_answers():
    answer = request.form.get('ans_text')
    quest_id = request.form.get('q_id')
    session['last_question'] = quest_id
    session['total'] += 1
    if check_answer(quest_id, answer):
        session['answers'] += 1

def test():
    if not ('quiz' in session) or int(session['quiz']) < 0:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            save_answers()
            return redirect(url_for('test'))

        next_question = get_question_after(session['last_question'], session['quiz'])
        if next_question is None or len(next_question) == 0:
            return redirect(url_for('result'))
        else:
            answers_list = [
                next_question[2], next_question[3], next_question[4], next_question[5]
            ]
            shuffle(answers_list)
            return render_template('test.html', question=next_question[1], quest_id=next_question[0], answers_list=answers_list)


def result():
    html = render_template('result.html', right=session['answers'], total=session['total'])
    end_quiz()
    return html

folder = os.getcwd()
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=folder, static_folder=folder)
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index, methods=['post', 'get'])
app.add_url_rule('/test', 'test', test, methods=['post', 'get'])
app.add_url_rule('/result', 'result', result, methods=['post', 'get'])
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'ThisIsSecretSecretSecretLife'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

start.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #D1E9F5;
            color: #555555;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .container {
            text-align: center;
        }

        h2 {
            color: #6CB4D6;
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        form {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #F0F8FF;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
            border: 2px solid #6CB4D6;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #F0F8FF;
            color: #555555;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        input[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #6CB4D6;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Викторина</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Выберите викторину:</h2>
        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
            <select name="quiz">
                {% for id, name in q_list %}
                    <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Выбрать"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and db_scripts.py (library with scripts)

```
import sqlite3
from random import randint

db_name = 'quiz.sqlite'
conn = None
cursor = None

def open():
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

def close():
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

def do(query):
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

def clear_db():
    ''' убивает все таблицы '''
    open()
    query = '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS quiz_content'''
    do(query)
    query = '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS question'''
    do(query)
    query = '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS quiz'''
    do(query)
    close()

def create():
    open()
    cursor.execute('''PRAGMA foreign_keys=on''')
    
    do('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
            name VARCHAR)''' 
    )
    do('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS question (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                question VARCHAR, 
                answer VARCHAR, 
                wrong1 VARCHAR, 
                wrong2 VARCHAR, 
                wrong3 VARCHAR)'''
    )
    do('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz_content (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                quiz_id INTEGER,
                question_id INTEGER,
                FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quiz (id),
                FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question (id) )'''
    )
    close()

def show(table):
    query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table
    open()
    cursor.execute(query)
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    close()

def show_tables():
    show('question')
    show('quiz')
    show('quiz_content')

def add_questions():
    questions = [
        ('Сколько месяцев в году имеют 28 дней?', 'Все', 'Один', 'Ни одного', 'Два'),
        ('Каким станет зеленый утес, если упадет в Красное море?', 'Мокрым?', 'Красным', 'Не изменится', 'Фиолетовым'),
        ('Какой рукой лучше размешивать чай?', 'Ложкой', 'Правой', 'Левой', 'Любой'),
        ('Что не имеет длины, глубины, ширины, высоты, а можно измерить?', 'Время', 'Глупость', 'Море', 'Воздух'),
        ('Когда сетью можно вытянуть воду?', 'Когда вода замерзла', 'Когда нет рыбы', 'Когда уплыла золотая рыбка', 'Когда сеть порвалась'),
        ('Что больше слона и ничего не весит?', 'Тень слона', 'Воздушный шар', 'Парашют', 'Облако'),
        ('Что такое у меня в кармашке?', 'Кольцо', 'Кулак', 'Дырка', 'Бублик')
    ]
    open()
    cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO question (question, answer, wrong1, wrong2, wrong3) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)''', questions)
    conn.commit()
    close()

def add_quiz():
    quizes = [
        ('Викторина 1', ),
        ('Викторина 2', ),
        ('Викторина-непоймикакая', )
    ]
    open()
    cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO quiz (name) VALUES (?)''', quizes)
    conn.commit()
    close()

def add_links():
    open()
    cursor.execute('''PRAGMA foreign_keys=on''')
    query = "INSERT INTO quiz_content (quiz_id, question_id) VALUES (?,?)"
    answer = input("Добавить связь (y / n)?")
    while answer != 'n':
        quiz_id = int(input("id викторины: "))
        question_id = int(input("id вопроса: "))
        cursor.execute(query, [quiz_id, question_id])
        conn.commit()
        answer = input("Добавить связь (y / n)?")
    close()


def get_question_after(last_id=0, vict_id=1):
    ''' возвращает следующий вопрос после вопроса с переданным id
    для первого вопроса передается значение по умолчанию '''
    open()
    query = '''
    SELECT quiz_content.id, question.question, question.answer, question.wrong1, question.wrong2, question.wrong3
    FROM question, quiz_content 
    WHERE quiz_content.question_id == question.id
    AND quiz_content.id > ? AND quiz_content.quiz_id == ? 
    ORDER BY quiz_content.id '''
    cursor.execute(query, [last_id, vict_id] )

    result = cursor.fetchone()
    close()
    return result 

def get_quises():
    ''' возвращает список викторин (id, name) 
    можно брать только викторины, в которых есть вопросы, но пока простой вариант '''
    query = 'SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY id'
    open()
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    close()
    return result 

def check_answer(q_id, ans_text):
    query = '''
            SELECT question.answer 
            FROM quiz_content, question 
            WHERE quiz_content.id = ? 
            AND quiz_content.question_id = question.id
        '''
    open()
    cursor.execute(query, str(q_id))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    close()    
    # print(result)
    if result is None:
        return False # не нашли
    else:
        if result[0] == ans_text:
            # print(ans_text)
            return True # ответ совпал
        else:
            return False # нашли, но ответ не совпал

def get_quiz_count():
    ''' необязательная функция '''
    query = 'SELECT MAX(quiz_id) FROM quiz_content'
    open()
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    close()
    return result 

def get_random_quiz_id():
    query = 'SELECT quiz_id FROM quiz_content'
    open()
    cursor.execute(query)
    ids = cursor.fetchall()
    rand_num = randint(0, len(ids) - 1)
    rand_id = ids[rand_num][0]
    close()
    return rand_id

def main():
    clear_db()
    create()
    add_questions()
    add_quiz()
    show_tables()
    add_links()
    show_tables()
    # print(get_question_after(0, 3))
    # print(get_quiz_count())
    # print(get_random_quiz_id())
    pass
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

here is also link for full folder - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QscF375wa5aANxMjbCwAD5lJ4T_PIUQ3?usp=drive_link

i tried to work with "def index" with hlml code itself, but id doesnt helped

Comment: Quick question: did you restart the app after changing your code? If not, kill current app, make sure your files are saved, and run it again - and see if the problem appears again

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your code says

```
next_question = get_question_after(session['last_question'], session['quiz'])
if next_question is None or len(next_question) == 0:
   return redirect(url_for('result'))
```

Since you said that submitting your form redirects you to `/result`, it means the above condition has been met. If you're expecting to have a value for `next_question`, then you should figure out why that isn't happening (maybe you don't have it saved in session which is where your code expects to get the value from)